# Is ipc message queue slower than normal application que in case of multi threaded application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am receiving requests through a tcp socket and processing those requests and sending those processed buffer to another socket.I receive 2 kinds of request and push them in 2 ipc message queue. Then 2 individual threads process them and send processed buffer to destination socket. But I still do not get my desired speed. If I use normal application(implemented by code) que, will it increase speed?